# Virtual PC 2007 host is 64 bit XP Pro - guest is 32 bit XP Pro - cannot access shared folder

Tags: visual-studio-2008, virtual-pc, caspol

I've Googled, I've Caspol to death, but I still cannot load a VS2008 solution from a drive on the host machine. I get the project location not trusted message.

When I try:

```
Caspol -q -machine -addgroup 1 -url file://d:/* FullTrust -name "D Drive"
```

VS2008 starts to open the solution, then crashes with no error message - just disappears.
The only thing I can see that is different from some of the solutions I've seen is that I have a 64 bit host system, and the guest is 32.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: I guess you checked already, but does the solution open up correctly if you copy it to a folder inside the VM (so you are not using a shared folder). Maybe the .ncb, .suo or another of the solution files are corrupted. Plus: Is the latest SP installed for everything?

Comment: Just curious... Are you trying to debug a service on the guest machine?  I can't think of too many good reasons to run Visual Studio inside of Virtual PC.  You might want to look at msvsmon.exe in that case.

Comment: Divo - solution opens correctly in VM if I copy it.
Jesse - no, it's not a service. Lots of people run VS inside a VM - in fact, I thought that was the way to go!

Answer (score 0):

It may not be the best solution, but have you tried using dropbox to get around this issue?